# Git diff reports new/old mode, after config.filemode=false

Tags: git, diff

I want to compare branch1 and branch2.

1. git diff branch1 branch2
2. diff --git a/User.java b/User.java

old mode 100644

new mode 100755
.

.

.

[I already set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28xGX.png)
[git config --add core.filemode false].

[~/.gitconfig -> filemode=false].

But still new/old mode appear..
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As far as Git is concerned, this isn't a problem.  You are comparing two *commits*.  These commits exist.  Nothing in these two commits will ever change.  That includes the fact that in commit `a`, `User.java` has mode `100644`, and in commit `b`, `User.java` has mode `100755`.  These will remain the same forever; `git diff` will compare them and find them to be different.

Configuring `core.filemode` to `false` is all about controlling how the file's mode in the *index* is updated.  Neither the index nor the work-tree is a commit.  The index, which is also called the *staging area*, provides a place in which you can build the *next* commit.

You can manipulate any index file mode, at any time, using `git update-index --chmod`.  Whatever you set it to (`100644` or `100755` with `-x` or `+x`), that mode will be recorded—forever!—in the *next* commit you make.  Manipulating file modes manually like this is annoying, but always possible.

It's your operating system's responsibility to save and update the file's mode in your work-tree.  If your operating system does this correctly, you can set `core.filemode` to `true` and use the operating system's mode to control the index / staging area's mode.  This is generally seen as the more convenient way to control the mode in a future commit.  If your operating system is faulty, however, you can set `core.filemode` to false to tell Git to ignore the work-tree modes and use only the mode stored in the index / staging-area.

When Git creates a new repository (with `git init` or `git clone`, Git probes the operating system's behavior.  If the work-tree's file system behaves correctly, Git sets `core.filemode` to `true` to make using Git more convenient.  If your work-tree's file system behaves incorrectly, Git sets `core.filemode` to `false` so as not to pick up incorrect settings from the incorrect operating system.  You can override Git's configuration (with a local configuration setting—a global one will not work as the repository already has a local setting, from that initial creation step) if you like, but that will never affect any existing commit.  No part of any existing commit can be changed.

Comment: Always been using that feature in a cargo cult way. Thanks a lot for the underlying causes. Much clearer now.